# What do silver/gold tools do and how can I get them?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I remember in Wild World, the gold shovel could plant money trees and was acquired by burying a normal shovel for a day.  The other golden tools had special abilities too.  In New Leaf, I have read that there are also silver tools.  What do the silver/gold tools do and how can I get them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Silver and Gold Tools are upgraded versions of the regular versions of the tools, which usually confer a benefit like making it easier to catch things, better durability, etc. The acquisition methods vary depending on the tool.

### Axes

#### Silver Axe

- Upgrade: Always creates [rare stump designs](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Special_Stump_Patterns), lasts longer than the regular axe
- Cost: 8 Medals
- Acquisition: Buy at [Tortimer's Island](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Island) when it comes into rotation

#### Gold Axe

- Upgrade: Chops down trees faster and is unbreakable
- Cost: -
- Acquisition: Buy 50 tree saplings at the [Garden Center](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Gardening_Store) and [Leif](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Leif) will give it to you

### Fishing Rods

#### Silver Fishing Rod

- Upgrade: Fish bite down longer on the hook, giving you more time between when the bobber sinks and when you can hit <kbd>A</kbd> to set the hook
- Cost: 500 bells
- Acquisition: Donate 30 Fish to the [Museum](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Museum) and it'll come into rotation at the [Museum Gift Shop](http://acwiki3ds.wikispaces.com/Museum)

#### Gold Fishing Rod

- Upgrade: Fish bite down even longer
- Cost: -
- Acquisition: Catch all 72 fish and then talk to [Chip](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Chip) during the [Fishing Tourney](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Fishing_Tourney)

### Nets

#### Silver Net

- Upgrade: Net radius is increased, effectively making it easier to catch bugs
- Cost: 500 bells
- Acquisition: Donate 30 bugs to the Museum and it'll come into rotation in the Museum Gift Shop

#### Gold Net

- Upgrade: Net radius increased further
- Cost: -
- Acquisition: Catch all 72 bugs and then talk to [Nat](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Nat) during a [Bug-Off Tournament](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Bug_Off)

### Shovels

#### Silver Shovel

- Upgrade: When hitting the daily [money rock](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Money_Rock), it'll have a chance to produce gems instead
- Cost: 500 bells
- Acquisition: Donate 15 fossils to the Museum and it'll come into rotation in the Museum Gift Shop

#### Gold Shovel

- Upgrade: You can plant Bells to possibly produce [Money Trees](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Money_Tree)
- Cost: -
- Acquisition: Buy 50 fertilizer at the Garden Center and Leif will give it to you

### Slingshots

#### Silver Slingshot

- Upgrade: Shoots 2 pellets at once
- Cost: -
- Acquisition: A present with 2 silver balloons will fly by with the Silver Slingshot inside

#### Gold Slingshot

- Upgrade: Shoots 3 pellets at once
- Cost: -
- Acquisition: A present with 3 gold balloons will fly by with the Gold Slingshot

There is conflicting information on whether or not you need to have popped 16 regular balloons before the Silver/Gold Balloons will appear. [Bidoof Crossing](http://bidoofcrossing.tumblr.com/post/39707937688/tool-guide) does not mention the requirement at all, the [AC Wikia](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Silver_Tool#Silver_Slingshot_2) and [AC Wikispace](http://acwiki3ds.wikispaces.com/Tools) say it's only required for Silver and not [Gold](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Golden_Tool#Golden_Tools), and [IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/animal-crossing-new-leaf/Tools) says it's *only* required for the Gold Slingshot. I've personally not kept track of the number of balloons I've popped so far, so I cannot test myself.

### Watering Cans

#### Silver Watering Can

- Upgrade: Waters 5 spots at once (up, down, left, and right in addition to target)
- Cost: -
- Acquisition: Buy 50 flowers at the Gardening Center and Leif will give it to you

#### Gold Watering Can

- Upgrade: Waters 9 spots at once (completely surrounding the target in addition to target itself)
- Cost: -
- Acquisition: Maintain a Perfect Town status for 15 days

Comment: A friend of mine got a gold slingshot before silver (she ended up with both) so I'm pretty sure the slingshots are just random, there's no criteria

Answer (score 4):

### Silver Tools

- Silver watering can: Purchase 50 bags of flower seeds from Leif's gardening store. Can water up to five flowers at a time.
- Silver axe: Rarely appears in island gift shop. Costs 8 medals. Always produces rare tree stump designs, and is more durable than a regular axe.
- Silver slingshot: After shooting down at least 16 balloons, appears as a present under two silver balloons. Shoots two pellets at a time.

These silver tools can only be purchased from the museum after building the Museum Renovation public work, and cost 500 bells.

- Silver shovel: Donate 15 fossils to the museum. Can produce gems from the daily money rock.
- Silver net: Donate 30 bugs to the museum. Increased net size.
- Silver fishing rod: Donate 30 fish to the museum. Fish bite longer.

### Golden Tools

- Gold shovel: Buy 50 fertilizers. Can produce Bell Trees.
- Gold net: Catch all the insects in game and talk to bug catching tournament host. Greatly increased net size.
- Gold fishing rod: Catch all fish in game and talk to fishing tournament host. Fish bite much longer.
- Gold watering can: Keep your town in the "perfect town" status for 15 days, and you'll get the golden watering can from Isabelle. Waters 9 flowers at a time.
- Gold Axe: Buy 50 tree saplings from the gardening shop. Never breaks, cuts trees faster, and sometimes creates a rare stump pattern
- Gold slingshot: Found randomly in the sky, has three gold balloons. Shoot all down and inside will be the gold slingshot. Shoots three pellets at a time.

The Timer, Megaphone, and Toy Hammer do not come in any variant besides standard.

Answer (score 0):

After you have shot down 14 balloons, there is a chance of a toolbox flying over head. The toolbox usually contain the silver slingshot, but rarely, contains the gold slingshot.

Shoot it down to unlock the slingshot.

You do not need to shoot down another 14 balloons. Once the first lot of 14 have been shot down, there is always a chance of this happening, regardless of if it has happened before, or if you have already shot one down.